# materializecss плагин datepicker работает не корректно или можно настроит место положение и высоту модалку года

Tags: javascript, vue.js, materialize-css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

materializecss плагин  datepicker работает не корректно или можно настроит место положение и высоту  модалку года

когда пользователь щелкает, чтобы выбрать год, модальное окно выходит из границы браузера, отображается только 3 года, в результате пользователи не могут выбрать нужный год – Mirjalol 7 часов назад

Comment: Что **именно** работает некорректно?

Comment: Как это что-то должно работать корректно?

Comment: когда пользователь щелкает, чтобы выбрать год, модальное окно выходит из границы браузера, отображается только 3 года, в результате пользователи не могут выбрать нужный год